# Why is Reduce in Mathematica giving solution in other symbols that don't exist in original equation

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, constraint

Here is an example:

```
Reduce[P/Q < (P - X)/(Q - X) && X > 0 && P > 0 && Q > 0 && P > Q, {X}, Integers]
```

The solution to above equation is:

```
(C[1] | C[2] | C[3]) ∈ Integers && 
C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && 
C[3] >= 0 && P == 3 + C[1] + C[2] + C[3] && 
Q == 2 + C[1] + C[2] &&  
X == 1 + C[2]
```

How do I interpret it? What is `C` and why are number 1, 2 and 3 in brackets? The documentation of reduce does not use this notation in any of the examples. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html

Comment: A fundamental concept of the syntax is that all built-in names begin with upper-case letters (or `$` followed by an upper-case letter). When *you* used upper-case letters for your own variables, you may have obscured that syntactical fact (you *may* use upper-case letters for your own names, but it's not advisable). On the other hand, `C` is an upper-case letter, which tells you at once that it's the name of a built-in object, hence that you should at once consult the Documentation!

Comment: Thanks @murray. :)

Comment: It is noted under Scope > Basic Uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C[1]`, `C[2]`, etc. are each a single variable. Think of them as constant $C_1$, $C_2$, etc.

There are infinitely many solutions to your equation and this is how the solution can be expressed.

Here's a simpler example which may be instructive.

```
Reduce[Sin[x] == 0, x, Reals]
(* C[1] ∈ Integers && (x == 2 π C[1] || x == π + 2 π C[1]) *)
```

Think about how you would express the solution to $\sin x = 0$, and it will be clear why `Reduce` gives this result.

The documentation you should look at is [C](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html).

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs. :) I get it now. The above values indicate that as long as X >= 1, Q >= 2 and P >= 3 and P > Q. The above equation will be true. Is my interpretation correct?